# Function calling from main() in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, header-files, program-entry-point

I have created a class  called Login_Class and a header file for the class. From the main method i am calling a function which is in the Login_Class. My problem is , i am getting 2 errors which are not letting me to compile this simple program. Since am new to c++ , i am not familiar with the errors.

Here is my login class implementation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include "Login_Class.h"
using namespace std;

 string checkUserType(string userType)
        {
           if(userType=="Admin")
            {
                return "Administrator";
            }
            if(userType=="HR")
            {
                return "HR";
            }
            if(userType=="staff")
            { 
                return "staff";
            }
        }
```

Here is the header file of the Login_Class

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#ifndef Login_Class_h
#define Login_Class_h
using namespace std;

class Login_Class
{
public: 

string checkUserType(string userType);
};

#endif
```

Here is my main method code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"Login_Class.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){


    Login_Class log;
    string name=log.checkUserType("Admin"); //calling the function in the login_Class
    cout<<name<<endl;

         }
```

Here are the errors which i am getting

[image]

What am i doing wrong here ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post the actual error text rather than a picture, I can't read that last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing:

```
string checkUserType(string userType)
```

to

```
string Login_Class::checkUserType(string userType)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `include guards` will help. In header files create follownig preprocessor block:

```
#ifndef _H_LOGIN_CLASS
#define _H_LOGIN_CLASS

////yourcode...




#endif
```

Include guards prevents during compation from reading the same file more than one time. And also boosts compilation speed.

Comment: The original code already has include guards. In contrast to your suggestion, it doesn't use reserved symbol names. In C++ symbols starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase character are reserved for use by the implementation. Include guards also have very little impact on compile times. Precompiled headers and the [`/MP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx) compiler switch, on the other hand, do.